# Как записать rtsp поток в opencv в лучшем качестве?

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

ок, я отобразил поток в окне и записал в каком-то качестве в output.avi.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.11.35")
cv2.namedWindow('main', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 12,(int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4))))

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        cv2.imshow('main', frame)
        out.write(frame)

    ch = cv2.waitKey(5)
    if ch == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
out.release()
```

как просто записать поток в минимально изменённом состоянии?
ffmpeg может писать столько fps сколько есть, может копировать кодек.
тут это как сделать?

Comment: А можно нескромный вопрос — что мешает вместо opencv использовать этот самый ffmpeg?

Comment: Нужно записывать и анализировать поток. Я думал с Ffmpeg:
Ffmpeg берёт rtsp и разделяет на два потока. Оригинальный и подготовленный (обрезанный по краям). Opencv берёт и анализирует подготовленный и записывает результаты в лог. На выходе нужно получить несколько суток видео в максимально возможном качестве и результаты анализа в txt. Но как создать rtsp поток в ffmpeg? Пока пробую обойтись без ffmpeg.

Comment: Можно отправить подготовленный поток в stdout и в питоне захватить его с помощью subprocess.PIPE, не используя файлы вообще. Правда, я не работал с opencv и не знаю, сможет ли он захватить поток из пайпа, так что подробнее не подскажу